# Select an setting item of Elementor plugin using jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, select, elementor

I developed a widget called premium carousel. There I used **select2** settings field for the carousel item which is loaded from the Elementor library. When a template is published in **Elementor Libray** and refresh the carousel editor page then that published template is populated in that select2 setting field.

When in editor page, I save a template, then that template is not populated directly. To overcome this problem I was using the jquery ajax. But the problem is "After clicking the save template button, in success function I can not select that select field in where I want to append the new item."

[image: I want to select the highlighted area select html tag]

I tried this way for checking

```
(function( $ ) {

    $(document).ready( function() {

    $('.elementor-control-premium_carousel_slider_content select[data-setting=premium_carousel_slider_content] ').css('width', '60px !important');
    // not selecting this element


    $('body').on('click', 'button#elementor-template-library-save-template-submit',
        { name:'elementor-control-premium_carousel_slider_content select[data-setting=premium_carousel_slider_content' }, function( event ) {
            console.log( $('.' + event.data.name ).length );
      // logs 0 which mean that element does not exists in document. Coming from another javascript code
    });
   });

})(jQuery);
```

How can I get rid of this problem? Any idea please?

Comment: Do it by ID... `$('#elementor-control-default-c369').css('width', '60px !important');`

Comment: This ID is being changed on different carousel widget and every time when editor is open. This ID won't work for me. Also using console tool of chrome I tried, but not wokring @AlessandroL.

Comment: Can changes the select classes? Example: `elementor-select2` class can change?

Comment: That class will be same all time regardless page loading or carousel sliders. @AlessandroL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this

```
$('.elementor-select2[data-setting=premium_carousel_slider_content]').each(function(index){
   alert($(this).html());
});
```

I'll wait your feedback

Comment: I got my problems. Actually that element is coming from underscore template. Just when I click on editor preview of the slider, then that html tag `select` is available.